# Shift values based on condition in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe `df1`:

```
      A     B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
  0   1    11    a    XX   50   Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan
  1   2    12    b    YY   10   Nan  1    Nan  Nan  Nan
  2   1    11    c    ZZ   70   Nan  Nan  11   12   56
  3   Nan  Nan   Nan  Nan  0    6    10   c    DD   45
  4   3     7    e    MM   12   1    7    d    LL   64
  5   Nan  Nan   Nan  Nan  2    89   Nan  f    KK   13
```

I would like to built a resulting dataframe `df2` in such a way that if a value is present in any row for attribute `F` (any value but not "Nan"), then copy the values of `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, `J` for that particular row and paste them in `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` respectively. Hence values of last three rows should be copied.

The resulting dataframe `df2` should be some thing like this:

```
       A     B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J   
   0   1    11    a    XX   50   Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan
   1   2    12    b    YY   10   Nan  1    Nan  Nan  Nan
   2   1    11    c    ZZ   70   Nan  Nan   11   12   56
   3   6    10    c    DD   45    6    10   c    DD   45
   4   1     7    d    LL   64    1    7    d    LL   64
   5   89   Nan   f    KK   13    89   Nan  f    KK   13
```

Any help would be surely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [102]: df.loc[df.F.notnull(), list('ABCDE')] = \
              df.loc[df.F.notnull(), list('FGHIJ')].values

In [103]: df
Out[103]:
      A     B  C   D   E     F     G    H    I     J
0   1.0  11.0  a  XX  50   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
1   2.0  12.0  b  YY  10   NaN   1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
2   1.0  11.0  c  ZZ  70   NaN   NaN   11   12  56.0
3   6.0  10.0  c  DD  45   6.0  10.0    c   DD  45.0
4   1.0   7.0  d  LL  64   1.0   7.0    d   LL  64.0
5  89.0   NaN  f  KK  13  89.0   NaN    f   KK  13.0
```